# My phone thinks it's charging

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, battery, charging

After upgrading my Galaxy Nexus to 4.0.4, it keeps thinking the cable is being plugged in and out all the time. The battery discharges at a normal rate, even though the screen keeps lighting up as a result of the random plug events. I don't think this is a hardware issue, but I've not completely discarded the idea either.

Has anyone experienced this? Is this a known issue? Anything I can do about it?

Comment: A factory data reset is in order. If you're on Custom ROM, the ROM might be buggy.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't solve the issue. Now, the phone thinks it's always charging. At least it stopped the screen constantly lighting up, I guess.

Comment: You aren't on a custom ROM, are you?

Comment: Nope, I'm using stock Android 4.0.4. It isn't even branded by my provider.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem recently on my Nexus S upgraded to stock ICS.
The problems were:

- Connecting the phone to the AC charger would sometimes show the phone to be charging, while the battery level was not actually increasing and sometimes the opposite.
- Connecting the phone through USB to my laptop would allow it to charge, but my laptop used to throw a "Unrecognized USB Device" error.
- The battery level displayed on my phone was misleading. For eg, the battery level was shown to be 44%, but when I restarted it, it suddenly dropped to 19%.
- Shutting it down while connected to AC charger would cause it to hang on the shutting down screen till I remove the charger.
- Connecting it to an AC charger while switched off would cause it to automatically turn on.

A little research on the net yielded [this dicussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mobile/android-devices/i_pX09Jbrmo) on the Google Product forums.
The alleged problem was the pin in the phone's USB port, and the solution was to bend it upwards a little using a penknife.

I was a little wary of taking things into my own hands, so I went to a nearby Samsung service center where they replaced the charging connector, and I haven't faced any problems since.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your charging port is not shorting across:

Turn off phone, remove battery, and use a pin or similar pirze middle piece in the charger slot so it is central in the slot, as when pushing in the charger it can be moved up or down and cause a short to side, which gives the charging signal on phone.

When having it fairly central, replace the battery, turn your device on, and see what happens.

This worked for my phone which was driving me potty bleeping for charge etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same proplem and found a workaround:

My Nexus keeps switching between charging and discharging while it is not connected. That keeps the screen on - which causes massive battery drain.

As a workaround I found a root app to keep the screen off, called [Screen Standby](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nkahoang.screenstandby). The CPU is still doing work but at least the screen doesn't draw power since I installed it.

Comment: Well, this only attenuates the symptoms and gives you back a longer battery life, but the problem still exists. In another post, someone mentioned that *air-cleaning* the port with compressed air did the trick: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/32407/15713

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem: first of all, I removed my charger from my mobile. Then I went to the developer option in my phone's settings. I went to "Select USB Configuration" (or select USB connection type). It was set to Charging, but I changed this option to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). After that, I plugged in my charger and my phone was charging.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is an application running with a WAKEUP flag.

If you were rooted, a simple `adb logcat` would get to the bottom of it.

But what it comes down to is uninstalling that app-- perhaps reviewing the seedy ones?

The last time this happened to me, it was a kamasutra app.

Comment: The device doesn't wake up due to a misbehaving app but because it thinks it's charging. (hence the title of the question)

Comment: They said that the phone thinks its charging. They did not say the LED lights up, but rather that the screen lights up--- *as if* it does when its charging.  

This is because the system has received a WAKEUP flag.

Comment: I asked him to clarify.